# Instruments Pointing to Leak in Framework -- Found Leak was Somewhere Else (Why?)

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, instruments

I'm becoming more familiar with Instruments for debugging, and it's much easier to use than it initially appeared. This problem was posted so I could understand why it was pointing to one line of code as the source of my leak, and what the logical process would be to resolve it.

The answer may benefit someone else trying to use instruments. I haven't seen a lot of details on how to use it. (There is the Instruments User's Guide, which is a good start, but that's about it.)

In this case, Instruments was pointing to a repeatable leak at the line returning a JSONValue (type NSDictionary) from the SBJSON framework. I tried various things to isolate the problem (see below), and in every case, Instruments still pointed to the line returning the JSON dictionary object.

One more thing that I tried was the NSJSONSerializer available with iOS 5. Instruments again pointed to the same line. Clearly, Instruments was misleading me. **(Why? What can I do to avoid/improve this?)**

To make a long story short, the problem was not where Instruments was pointing, but it was within the instance that contained that line. In this case, there were two properties, whose values were derived from the deserialized JSON dictionary, that were not being released.

I arrived at this conclusion through trial and error, commenting out code and replacing the returned values with literal strings. (I'm sorry if I put a fright in you, Stig!)

---

An earlier update

Here is a revision of my post. I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the failure of an SBJSON returned string not being autoreleased. I'd like some other thoughts on whether my process of elimination makes sense, what conclusion should I make, and how to resolve this.

The original question is down below. I have focused on this code:

```
    NSString *resultsGeocodeLiteralString = @"{... the rest of the string ...}";        
    NSAutoreleasePool *aPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
/*1*/     NSDictionary *dico = [resultsGeocodeLiteralString JSONValue]; // <-- Instruments still points here.
/*2a*/    self.resultsGeoCode = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dico copyItems:YES];
/*2b*/    [self.resultsGeoCode release];
    [aPool release];
```

Here I use a literal string `resultsGeocodeLiteralString` that is converted to an NSDictionary using the SBJSON JSONValue method. I tested with the literal string to divorce the problem from the original input argument and its memory management.

Ignoring the autorelease pool for a moment, I tried this code, deep copying the JSONValue result into a the property `self.resultsGeoCode`.

Instruments pointed to the leak being at the line calling the JSONValue method.

This makes me think something is wrong with autoreleasing. So I wrapped this code in a short autorelease pool. This had no effect on the results. Instruments showed the same leak, pointing to the same line.

---

Original Question Below:

Instruments is pointing to this code as a source of a couple of leaks. I have run out of ideas on how to resolve this. This method is in a object of type `Geocoder`

First, here is the code. Instruments is pointing the the line marked /*1*/. I tried deep copying the NSDictionary returned as a JSONValue (/*2a*/ and /*2b*/), just to distance the problem from the returned object, but that didn't make any difference.

```
- (NSString *) processResults:(NSString *) resultsGeoCodeString {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

/*1*/     self.resultsGeoCode = [resultsGeoCodeString JSONValue];
/*2a*/    self.resultsGeoCode = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.resultsGeoCode copyItems:YES];
/*2b*/    [self.resultsGeoCode release]; // It's retained twwice in the line above.

/* copy a stirng */
    self.previousStatusCode = [self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"status"];

    if ([self.previousStatusCode isEqualToString:@"OK"] == YES) {

/* Break it down. Results might be a single object or an array of objects. If it's an array, just take the first one. */
        NSArray *address_components;
        NSDictionary *geom;
        if ([[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            address_components = [[(NSArray *)[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address_components"];
            geom = [[[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        }
        else {
            address_components = [[[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"address_components"];
            geom = [[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        }

/* deep copy the geometry */
        self.geometry = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:geom copyItems:YES];
        [self.geometry release]; // it is retained twice in the line above

/* copy a string */
        self.formattedAddress = [[[self.resultsGeoCode objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"formatted_address"];

/* copy the strings from specific types */
        NSArray *typesArray;
        for (NSDictionary *address_component in address_components) {
            if ([[address_component objectForKey:@"types"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                typesArray = [address_component objectForKey:@"types"];
            else
                typesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[address_component objectForKey:@"types"], nil];

            for (NSString *componentType in typesArray) {

                if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"locality"]) 
                    self.city = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];

                else if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"administrative_area_level_1"]) 
                    self.region = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];

                else if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"country"]) {
                    self.country = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];
                    self.countryCode = [address_component objectForKey:@"short_name"];
                }
                else if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"postal_code"]) 
                    self.postalCode = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];

                else if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"street_number"]) 
                    self.streetNumber = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];

                else if ([componentType isEqualToString:@"route"]) 
                    self.route = [address_component objectForKey:@"long_name"];

            }
        }
    }

    [pool release];

/* a retained property set to nil -- not needed anymore */
    self.resultsGeoCode = nil;

/* return a string */    
    return self.previousStatusCode;
}
```

All NSString properties have the copy attribute. All NSDictionary properties have a retain attribute. You can see I do a deep copy of any dictionary items.

Here is the dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc {
/* NSString properties with copy attribute */
    self.streetNumber = nil;
    self.route = nil;
    self.city = nil;
    self.region = nil;
    self.country = nil;
    self.postalCode = nil;
    self.previousStatusCode = nil;
    self.region = nil;

/* I have tried it with and without these releases  of the dictionary properties */
    if (location_) [location_ release];
    if (geometry_) [geometry_ release];
    if (regionGeometries_) [regionGeometries_ release];
    if (resultsGeoCode_) [resultsGeoCode_ release];

/* I would have thought these would be sufficient to release the retained properties */
//    self.location = nil;
//    self.geometry = nil;
//    self.regionGeometries = nil;
//    self.resultsGeoCode = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Instruments says the leaks object is an NSCFString and the responsible frame (I don't know what that is) is -[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:].

I hope there's not too much code here to look through, but I stumped. Also, I'm curious if there are any obvious misunderstandings that show up as to how property setters behave. (All setters and getters are synthesized.)

Comment: I can abstract the problem once I understand it, and I'll be happy to do that. I have narrowed this down pretty well I think, and I'm trying to understand some principals here. Once I understand them, they'll be shared.

Comment: Jim, what version of SBJson are you using? The current master (3.1alpha) is using ARC. This should preclude any leaks. Can you see if you still see the problem with this version?

Comment: Hi, Stig. I am using 3.0.1. I just resolved the issue, and you'll be happy to know it is not SBJSON! I'll revise my question to reflect that, and show what the problem was. I tried NSJSONSerializer and the same problem occurred. Instruments still pointed at the JSON serialization line of code. (I switched back to SBJSON because I customize the serialization of m objects.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not 100% answer, because we do not know what happens next and what happened before.

I am not sure, but there are some things you do not have to do:
Firstly:

```
/*2a*/    self.resultsGeoCode = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[resultsGeoCodeString JSONValue] copyItems:YES];
```

instead of those 3 lines.
If you do not need the argument of the function `resultsGeoCodeString` then you can release it.

Secondly:

```
self.geometry = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:geom copyItems:YES];
[self.geometry release];
```

Why are you releasing it right after you've allocated this object? Release it after you've done with this object. The same as the previous point.

And before the `[pool release];` add line `[self.resultsGeoCode release];` `self.resultsGeoCode = nil;` or earlier.

I suggest you using ARC instead of manual retain counting.

Comment: Thanks for helping. (1) Can you clarify what you mean in your first recommendation, "If you do not need the argument..."? `resultsGeoCodingString" is an NSString that I am converting from JSON to an NSDictionary. My thought is that the returned object was not autoreleasing, or if it was, it would take some of the extracted objects with it. This is why I shifted to copying strings and deep copying dictionaries. (2) My understanding is that the setter for a retained property will call retain. So this object is retained 2X, as I also used init to create it. But this shouldn't cause a leak.

Comment: if you somewhere before allocate the resultsGeoCodingString you should release it. If you don't - leave it as it is.
`self.geometry = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:geom copyItems:YES];` as I understand the memory management, here you retain the `self.geometry` once.

Comment: I looked into your suggestion that the problem could originate with the argument `resultsGeoCodingString` and didn't resolve the problem. I think I have narrowed it down now what may be an SBJSON problem, and I'll revise my original question to reflect what I have done.

Comment: @Jim show us, how do you get your `resultsGeoCodingString`. That may help us to give you the right answer.